# Is there a way to add Pop-up Exceptions using the chrome API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension that includes a feature to launch the [Omniture DigitalPulse Debugger](http://blogs.omniture.com/2010/11/17/meet-the-new-digitalpulse-debugger/) from a context-menu link. The debugger can be launched from a fixed number of domains that are stored in the extension's settings.

Unfortunately, when users click the link on a domain without a Pop-Up Exception, the pop-up is blocked until they allow it and/or manually add an exception. Is it possible to automatically add exceptions when the extension is installed or updated?

Currently, the click handler launches the debugger using a "javascript:" URL. There may be a better way to do it, but it is the only way I've found to allow the pop-up to have access to the tab's context. Here is the code:

```
/**
 * loads DigitalPulse omniture debugger in a new window
 * @param {Object} info Click event info
 * @param {Object} tab Tab info
 */
omnitureDebugger: function (info, tab) {
    var script = 'window.open("", "dp_debugger", "width=600,height=600,location=0,menubar=0,status=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1").document.write("<script id=\'dbg\' src=\'http://www.digitalpulse.omniture.com/dp/debugger.js\'></"+"script>");'
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: "javascript:" + script });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use [chrome.contentSettings.popups](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/beta/contentSettings.html#property-popups) API to add an exception. This API is available in Chrome 16 or later (currently in the beta channel).

Comment: Merci beaucoup! I searched high and low through the docs, and I could not find this. I suppose I'll have to wait 3 or 4 months to implement this. Thanks again.

Comment: I hopefully won't be 3 or 4 months. Chrome 16 should be released to the stable channel ~6 weeks after Chrome 15 (which was released on October 25).